# EJB Injection for Servlet - JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x

I'm trying to inject an EJB to a servlet using JBoss7 and its not working. The code works fine on JBoss 6 I package the EJB code out of the WAR, and the interfaces with the WAR but I don't get injection in the SERVLETS(GWT Servlets).

My code looks like

Interface:

```
@Local
public interface MyService{
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Stateless(name = "MyService")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
}
```

Servlet

```
@EJB(name = "MyService")
private MyService service;
```

The same implementation was working fine in JBoss AS 6. I ran out of ideas. Please help.

Comment: Perhaps it's because in JBoss AS 7 you have JBoss Modules and each deployment exists in its own 'module'; therefore it cannot see any artifacts outside of it? Try wrapping it into one EAR or defining the modules dependency between WAR and EJB-JAR.

Answer (score 2):

If your `EJB` is only a local one, you can put every thing in the war.

If there is only one implementation of the interface you can remove the name of the `EJB`, the container will resolve the `EJB` injection base on the type.  (You can remove the the interface all together with `EJB` 3.1).

If you need more, you should provide the archive (`EAR` or `WAR`) structure and some log entry (`EJB` list + error when making the injection).